# Plot ranges when plotting multiple things

Tags: r

R will automatically determine the plot ranges (`xlim`, `ylim`) from the first `plot()` call. But when you are plotting multiple things on a single plot, the subsequent calls to `plot()` might not fit in the frame, as in this case:

```
mu <- 8
sd <- 8

plot(function (x) dnorm(x, mu, sd, log = TRUE), xlim = c(0, 10)) # log likelihood
plot(function (x) (mu-x)/sd^2, col = "green", add = TRUE, xlim = c(0, 10)) # derivative log likelihood
```

I know I could first determine the ranges of all plot components myself and then `min` and `max` them together and pass the range to the first `plot()` call... but it is sooo inconvenient... and results in R scripts which are bulky and not easy to read.

Is there some simple way to handle this in R, am I missing something? I am sure libraries like ggplot or lattice have better solutions, would be interesting to see them, but I strongly prefer solution with the base R. Thanks! :)

**EDIT:** is it possible something like to defer the plotting of the plot until I call the last `plot()` and then plot everything? :-) This could be very elegant and the code would stay nicely compact :)

Comment: Try `curve(dnorm(x, mu, sd, log = TRUE), xlim = c(0, 10))` (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt your approach a little and define the functions beforehand.

```
fun1 <- function(x) dnorm(x, mu, sd, log=TRUE)
fun2 <- function(x) (mu-x)/sd^2
```

Then you easily may calculate the range of everything in the desired `xlim` of the plot –  here `0:10`.

```
y.range <- range(sapply(0:10, function(x) c(fun1(x), fun2(x))))
```

Finally rather use the already defined functions than repeat them in the `plot()` call. NB you may be looking for `curve()`, but it also works with `plot()` in this case.

```
curve(fun1, xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=y.range)
curve(fun2, col="green", add=TRUE, xlim=c(0, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something along this line:

```
plot(function (x) dnorm(x, mu, sd, log = TRUE), xlim = c(0, 10)) # log likelihood
par(new=TRUE)
plot.function(function (x) (mu-x)/sd^2, col = "green", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE) # derivative log 
axis(side = 4)
```

## Output

[image: test_out]